# error: [["c154ab40-1aaf-11e7-92ae-000c298f510d", "3044c8f0-1ab0-11e7-92ae-000c298f510d"]]

Tags: java, neo4j

I am working on neo4j database .
And I am using this :

```
query="match(n:learner) where "+endTime+"<=n.registrationtime<="+startTime+" "+ " return count(n) as total,collect(n.name) as name,"
```

to retrieve the data on a specific counter but collect function returns data in array form . 
 When I am taking this in String variable it returns value like this

> ["c154ab40-1aaf-11e7-92ae-000c298f510d",
>   "3044c8f0-1ab0-11e7-92ae-000c298f510d"]

I want this data in Array list so how can I convert this in arraylist.

I am using this code

```
try {
                    query="match(n:learner) where "+endTime+"<=n.registrationtime<="+startTime+" "
                            + " return count(n) as total,collect(n.name) as name";
                    System.out.println(query);

                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query.toLowerCase());
                    if(rs.next()){
                        int total = rs.getInt("total");
                        System.out.println("total="+total);

                        ArrayList<String> userids=new ArrayList<String>();
                        String name=rs.getString("name");
                        System.out.println("id="+name);
                        String[] userArray=name.split(",");
                        for(String user:userArray){
                            userids.add(user);
                            System.out.println("userids="+userids);
                        }
                       dataFatch.setTotal(total);
```

and from this code i m getting this result

> id=["c154ab40-1aaf-11e7-92ae-000c298f510d","3044c8f0-1ab0-11e7-92ae-000c298f510d"]
>   userids=[["c154ab40-1aaf-11e7-92ae-000c298f510d"]
>   userids=[["c154ab40-1aaf-11e7-92ae-000c298f510d",
>   "3044c8f0-1ab0-11e7-92ae-000c298f510d"]]

Answer (score 0):

```
for(String user:userArray){
    userids.add(user);
}
System.out.println("userids="+userids);
```

userids is an ArrayList. You just need to print it out of the loop, otherwise userids is printed at any iteration

to print them run this code afterwards:

```
for (String userid : userids){
    System.out.println("userid="+userid);
}
```

Comment: actually this code i have already used but still getting this result userids=[["c154ab40-1aaf-11e7-92ae-000c298f510d", "3044c8f0-1ab0-11e7-92ae-000c298f510d"]]  is there any other way to solve this .i want separate ids.

Comment: they are separated in your userids array. It is just the System.out.println that is printing them together. I will update the answer